# CakePHP updating multiple rows with record ids, same model

Tags: cakephp, model

I want to update a model. I have a query like this

```
UPDATE mymodels SET `myfield` = 100 WHERE `id`=12 OR `id`=13 OR `id`=14
// also the same:
UPDATE mymodels SET `myfield` = 100 WHERE `id` IN (12,13,14)
```

And I tried this:

```
$this->MyModel->updateAll(
    // fields
    array('MyModel.myfield' => 100),
    // conditions
    array('MyModel.id' => 12)
);
```

But I need to update 20 different records.
Record ids are like this 12, 13, 14 ....

Comment: **<=** means Less than or equal to. Don't you want 12 or greater (**>=**)? You probably want the **IN** operator though. I believe the correct syntax is to define an array of id's `$ids = array(12,13,14);`  Then use it in the conditions parameter `array('MyModel.id' => $ids)`

Comment: Sorry for typo. I fixed the greater and equal sign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the records you want to update are sequential, then try adding two conditions like this

```
$this->MyModel->updateAll(
    array('MyModel.myfield' => 100),
    // conditions
    array('MyModel.id >=' => 12, 'MyModel.id <=' => 20)
);
```

If there's no relation between indexes of ids, try using an array

```
$this->MyModel->updateAll(
    array('MyModel.myfield' => 100),
    // conditions
    array('MyModel.id' => array(12,13,14...))
);
```